# Return Code when opening Excel Files

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to open Excel files and I am getting two different error messages when I do.

First One:

[image: Error #1]

Second One:

[image: Error #2]

Any thoughts on why I'm getting these errors?  Windows 7 Professional is the OS I'm working on, MS Office 2013 is the program I'm using to open Excel files.

Comment: The first one is because you're missing an expected DLL, and the second appears to be an error in the VBA in that file.  Are you getting both these errors for each file?  Is this with ANY Excel file you try to open or just specific one(s)?

Comment: Happens on every file that I try to open.

Comment: If you just open Excel directly, do these pop up? If you create a new blank XLSX, save it and then try to open it, do they pop up then? If you start Excel in Safe mode (`excel /safe`) do they pop up?

Comment: Any idea what `Intrinzk` refers to? Google's results are all noise.

Comment: No idea what Intrinzk, came back to the office this morning, and the errors have resolved themselves.  Sorry if I wasted anyone's time, but I do appreciate the comments and help.